# How to add code to AppDelegate using SwiftUI Life Cycle

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, admob, appdelegate

I'm following Google's tutorial on how to integrate AdMob ads into my app. In the tutorial, they put some code into the App Delegate. I've only ever used the SwiftUI life cycle for apps, so I'm not even sure what the App Delegate is. However, the issue is that in the tutorial, they instruct to put this code in the App Delegate file:

`[[GADMobileAds sharedInstance] startWithCompletionHandler:nil];`

I'm trying to put this code into the `init()` of my app (aka the SwiftUI version of putting it into my App Delegate). However, as this doesn't seem to be Swift code, I can't use that line of code without receiving errors. What should I do to insert this code into my app `init()`?

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tH68C9KeRf8) tutorial at around 3:10 into the video.

Comment: That is objective-c not swift, I would look for a much newer video. If you google how to add the app delegate to SwiftUI you will find plenty of samples it is 1 line of code in the view and the basic app delegate has about 6 lines. I think hacking with swift has the simplest code. There is no pure SwiftUI way of using ads you will have to use UIKit and UIViewControllerRepresentsble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `init` might be too early, try in app delegate as follows

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil) // << here !!
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct YourApp: App {

    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine and easy to understand.